# Xamarin Forms Content Page: Change flow direction to Right to Left?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

how can I change the flow direction of a Xamarin Forms Content Page from Left to Right to Right to Left? something like Windows Phone Flow Direction property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Hodor thanks, there is no support for such a thing (at least at this time). a workaround for this when using list views is to create multiple list item templates with LTR/RTL directions and use them accordin g to the current UI culture.

Another workaround for other controls is to implement a renderer for each control type and change its HorizontalOptions or XAlignment according to the UI culture.

Comment: Hello, How can I write a renderer for each control for rtl support? can you please give me a sample? is this option possible for android,IOS and Windows phone?

Comment: Hi, please check this guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/ good luck

Answer (score 1):

it's 2017 and Xamarin forms does not support RTL yet..

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth mentioning that the Grial UI Kit product has just added RTL support.

[image]

[More details here](https://github.com/UXDivers/Grial-UI-Kit-Support/blob/master/rtl-page.md)

Answer (score 0):

Try latest In latest Xamarin forms 3.0.0

If you’re making apps that support right-to-left languages, we have great news for you: Xamarin.Forms 3.0 makes it easier than ever to flip layouts to match language direction!

When supporting languages such as Arabic and Hebrew that flow right-to-left, you may now tap into the very easy to use `FlowDirection` property on any `VisualElement` instead of using platform-specifics or effects as you may have used previously. Because you already know the direction the device prefers by accessing `Device.FlowDirection`, updating your UI could be as easy as adding this to the head of your page in XAML:

> FlowDirection="{x:Static Device.FlowDirection}"

For more information about updating your applications to support right-to-left layouts:

[Right-To-Left Localization in Xamarin.Forms Blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/right-to-left-localization-xamarin-forms/)

Answer (score -1):

You mean the navigation flow?

Usually left => right means adding a page on the navigation stack and right => left means removing it.

You can extend a navigation controller on the "native" C# code and make custom animations. There are many ways to do that. Here's an example in MonoTouch

```
public partial class ScreenController : UINavigationController
{
     private Page currentPage = null;

             private void setCurrentPage(Page p)
    {
        currentPage = p;
        //Using present View Controller: will set the current page to root.
        PresentViewController(new UINavigationController(currentPage.CreateViewController())
                            {
                                ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal,
                            }, true, null);

        //Using custom animation
        PushControllerWithTransition(this, currentPage.CreateViewController(), UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft);
    }

    public static void PushControllerWithTransition(this UINavigationController target, UIViewController controllerToPush,
        UIViewAnimationOptions transition)
    {
        UIView.Transition(target.View, 0.75d, transition, delegate()
        {
            target.PushViewController(controllerToPush, false);
        }, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I meant the layout direction, RTL or LTR. Is it possible to change it the same way we do it in the Windows Phone SDK?

Comment: I don't think so. The only orientation you can change on layouts is between vertical and horizontal.